# How to access a nested JSON field in PowerShell

Tags: json, azure, powershell

I'm trying to access a specific field in a JSON object created by Azure Advisor using PowerShell. I have the following object:

```
@{id=/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations/xxxx;
category=Cost;
impact=High;
impactedArea=Microsoft.Subscriptions/subscriptions;
description=Consider virtual machine reserved instance to save over your on-demand costs;
recommendationText=Consider virtual machine reserved instance to save over your on-demand costs;
recommendationTypeId=xxx; instanceName=xxxx;
additionalInfo=;
tags=;
ResourceId=/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations/xxxx}
```

In this, I want to access a field 'savingsCurrency' to compare in an if-statement. The field is nested in 'additionalInfo', which in turn is in the 'advisorRecommendation' object.

I have the following code now:

```
Write-Output "advisorrecommendation: $advisorRecommendation"

if (-not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($advisorRecommendation.additionalInfo)))
{
    $additionalInfo = $advisorRecommendation.additionalInfo | ConvertTo-Json
    Write-Output "additionalInfo: $additionalInfo"
    if (-not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($additionalInfo.savingsCurrency)))
    {
        $savingsCurrency = $additionalInfo.savingsCurrency | ConvertTo-Json
        Write-Output "Currency: $savingsCurrency"
    }
}
else
{
    $additionalInfo = $null
}
```

This code gives me the following outputs:

```
advisorrecommendation:
@{id=/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations/xxx; category=Cost; impact=High; impactedArea=Microsoft.Subscriptions/subscriptions; description=Consider virtual machine reserved instance to save over your on-demand costs; recommendationText=Consider virtual machine reserved instance to save over your on-demand costs; recommendationTypeId=xxxx; instanceName=xxxx; additionalInfo=; tags=; ResourceId=/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations/xxxx}
```

```
additionalInfo: {
    "annualSavingsAmount": "697",
    "reservedResourceType": "virtualmachines",
    "targetResourceCount": "4",
    "savingsCurrency": "USD",
    "savingsAmount": "58",
    "lookbackPeriod": "30",
    "displaySKU": "Standard_B2s",
    "displayQty": "4",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "region": "westeurope",
    "vmSize": "Standard_B2s",
    "subId": "xxxx",
    "scope": "Single",
    "term": "P1Y",
    "qty": "4",
    "sku": "Standard_B2s"
}
```

The 'savingsCurrency' field never passes the null/empty check, even though I can clearly see that the field in 'additionalInfo' is not empty or null. What is going wrong here? If I try the print without the preceeding existence check, it simply prints the additionalInfo object with .savingsCurrency appended like this:

```
savingsCurrency: {
    "annualSavingsAmount": "697",
    "reservedResourceType": "virtualmachines",
    "targetResourceCount": "4",
    "savingsCurrency": "USD",
    "savingsAmount": "58",
    "lookbackPeriod": "30",
    "displaySKU": "Standard_B2s",
    "displayQty": "4",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "region": "westeurope",
    "vmSize": "Standard_B2s",
    "subId": "xxxx",
    "scope": "Single",
    "term": "P1Y",
    "qty": "4",
    "sku": "Standard_B2s"
}.savingsCurrency
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$advisorRecommendation.additionalInfo` is an *object* with nested properties:

```
$advisorRecommendation.additionalInfo.savingsCurrency
# USD
```

but `$additionalInfo` is a *string* because you've converted the object to json before assigning it:

```
$additionalInfo = $advisorRecommendation.additionalInfo | ConvertTo-Json

$additionalInfo.GetType().FullName
# System.String
```

As a result, `$savingsCurrency = $additionalInfo.savingsCurrency` is trying to read the `savingsCurrency` property of a *string*, and strings don't have that property so you get `$null`.

What you want to do instead is keep a reference to the `$advisorRecommendation.additionalInfo` *object* instead and only convert it to json for the purpose of writing it to the console:

```
Write-Output "advisorrecommendation: $advisorRecommendation"

#   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
if ($advisorRecommendation.additionalInfo -ne $null)
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{

    # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    $additionalInfo = $advisorRecommendation.additionalInfo
    Write-Output "additionalInfo: $($additionalInfo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99)"
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    if (-not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($additionalInfo.savingsCurrency)))
    {
        $savingsCurrency = $additionalInfo.savingsCurrency
        Write-Output "Currency: $savingsCurrency"
    }
}
else
{
    $additionalInfo = $null
}
```

You should now see `Currency: USD` in your output.

Note that `$additionalInfo.savingsCurrency` is already a *string* so you don't need to use `ConvertTo-Json` to display the value unless you specifically want it to be formatted as a json string (i.e. `"USD"` with surrounding quotes and any special characters like `\` escaped, instead of the literal string value `USD`)

Comment: You are an absolute hero, indeed the problem was me mixing up the object types. Thanks for your very clear and precise answer, I have learned at thing or two for the future!

Answer (score 0):

> The 'savingsCurrency' field never passes the null/empty check, even though I can clearly see that the field in 'additionalInfo' is not empty or null. What is going wrong here?

You can check  not null and if condition like below:

```
$additionalInfo = $additionalInfo | ConvertFrom-Json
if (-not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($additionalInfo.savingsCurrency)))
    {
        $savingsCurrency = $additionalInfo.savingsCurrency | ConvertTo-Json
        Write-Output "Currency: $savingsCurrency"
    }
```

[image]

> How to access JSON field in PowerShell

To access any json filed you need to first convert it from json like below :

```
$additionalInfo = $additionalInfo | ConvertFrom-Json
$savingsCurrency= $savingsCurrency | ConvertFrom-Json
```

To access any field you can use dot operator:

```
$additionalInfo.savingsCurrency
```

[image]